# JProfiler 8.1.4 issue on Ubuntu 14.04.3 (64 bit)

Tags: java, java-8, netty, ubuntu-14.04, jprofiler

Could someone please offer hints on how to resolve the below JProfiler core dump issue?

I get a core dump when I try to remotely attach to my application started with the JProfiler 1.8.4 agent on a Ubuntu 14 64-bit under Java 1.8.

```
% java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/dump
    -agentpath:/data/jprofiler8/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=9999,nowait
    -Xms512m -Xmx512m -cp App

JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
JProfiler> Protocol version 41
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Starting up without initial configuration.
JProfiler> Listening on port: 9999.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
JProfiler> Updating configuration.
JProfiler> Retransforming 1214 class files.
JProfiler> ERROR: could not retransform all classes (113). Trying separately.
JProfiler> ERROR: could not retransform class Lio/netty/util/internal/JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator (113).

Error in `java': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fb055854050 ***
Aborted (core dumped)


% uname -a
Linux ip-10-98-83-227 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP
Thu Mar 12 11:16:15  UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

%java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you try this with the current version?

Comment: @ingo-kegelHi,  Ingo,  

Unfortunately I do not have a license for JProfiler v9, though I purchased a personal license for v8 just six months ago.

Comment: JProfiler 9 (trial license) dumps core too.

Comment: Please send the hserr_pid file of the crash to support@ej-technologies.com